# Windows - moving a folder into itself?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, directory, subdirectory

Using batch, cmd, or some other loophole, is it possible to move a directory inside itself?

This has no practical purpose, I'm just curious.

## Methods tried:

### 1

Manually moving the folder yields `The destination folder is a subfolder of the source folder`.

### 2

Using the `move` command yields `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.`

Perhaps there might be a way to override these errors?

Comment: How do you think this is supposed to be working? Have you ever tried to pack a suitcase in itself? If you did and succeeded, please do so again and send me video footage ;)

Comment: "moving" implies deletion of the original. The moved folder would then be inside... - where?

Comment: What does this even mean?

Comment: What would you expect the result to be? If you move `C:\folder` into itself, would the resulting folder be `C:\folder` or `C:\folder\folder`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it would be possible, it would be an important bug.
A folder must have a path to it to be accessible.
After moving it into itself or in one of its child folders, it would become inaccessible and all data in it would be inaccessible.

Using a diskeditor to bypass the OS can allow doing it, but after that it would be accesible only by passing the OS and using the physical adress on the disk device.

Comment: Sounds like a good place to hide passwords

Comment: @Graviton: the best place to hide passwords is your brain...

Comment: @Stephan: The human brain is secure but the human memory is not reliable! That is maybe the biggest problem there is for password protection.

Comment: @StefanMondelaers: either use a good brain or a [good password](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Answer (score 1):

No, this can't be done.  However, you could place a self-referencing shortcut or symbolic link inside a directory.